# how can i take small part(like 100 as a raw data) from normal distribution and change skewness and kurtosis?

Tags: matlab, random, distribution

```
x=randn(1,100000);
subplot(3,1,1) , plot(x)
subplot(3,1,2) , histogram(x);
moments={mean(x),std(x),skewness(x),kurtosis(x)};
display(moments)
y=3*x+1;
subplot(3,1,3) , histogram(y);
C=corrcoef(x,y)
```

---

I have done this until now.

I produced random numbers with standard normal distribution. Then, I want to plot the small parts and its histogram.

Also, I want to learn how to change skewness and kurtosis.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw samples from a distribution with some predefined mean, variance, skewness and kurtosis, you can use `pearsnd(mu,sigma,skew,kurt,m,n)` to create an m-by-n matrix of random variables. See the documentation for more info

http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pearsrnd.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a sinh-arcsinh transformation:

see: http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/96/4/761.abstract

Essentially if `f(x)` is your normal distribution, then replacing `x` with `x1`:

```
x1 = sinh(delta*asinh(x)- epsilon)
y1 = f(x1)
```

you get another distribution with a different skewness and kurtosis.